# When pinned object is passed to native code, its address is actually not fixed

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pinvoke, zlib

## The Problem

Even though I pinned object in managed code, the actual address passed to native code rarely changes.

How can I assure GC to pin the actual address passed to native code?

Situation : https://youtu.be/-v8GgS6mUY0

## Details

I am writing a C# wrapper library for `zlib` based on `zlibnet`.

But decompressing with `inflate()` always failed, returning `Z_STREAM_ERROR`.
The error was coming from `zlib`'s `inflateStateCheck()`.

**ZLibWrapper\ZLibWrapper\ZLibStreams.cs: DeflateStream()**

```
_zstream = new ZStream();

int ret;
if (this._compMode == CompressionMode.Compress)
    ret = ZLibNative.DeflateInit(ref _zstream, level, WriteType);
else
    ret = ZLibNative.InflateInit(ref _zstream, OpenType);
```

**ZLibWrapper\ZLibWrapper\ZLibStreams.cs: Read()**

```
int zlibError = ZLibNative.Inflate(ref _zstream, ZLibFlush.Z_NO_FLUSH);
```

**zlib-1.2.11\inflate.c: inflateStateCheck()**

```
state = (struct inflate_state FAR *)strm->state;
if (state == Z_NULL || state->strm != strm ||
    state->mode < HEAD || state->mode > SYNC)
    return 1; // Z_STREAM_ERROR
```

`state->strm` was set at `inflateInit2_`, and `strm` was set at `inflate`.

C#'s garbage collector moved address of `_zstream` in between, casuing `Z_STREAM_ERROR`.

Adding `GCHandle.Alloc(..., GCHandleType.Pinned)` to pin the address of `_zstream` addressed most of the issue, but now it is happening randomly.

**New code of DeflateStream()**

```
_zstream = new ZStream();
_zstreamPtr = GCHandle.Alloc(_zstream, GCHandleType.Pinned); // NEW!

int ret;
if (this._compMode == CompressionMode.Compress)
    ret = ZLibNative.DeflateInit(ref _zstream, level, WriteType);
else
    ret = ZLibNative.InflateInit(ref _zstream, OpenType);
```

After some debugging, I found out `_zstream` was pinned but the actual address passed to `zlib`'s `inflate()` sometimes changes.

```
[Managed Side]
inflateInit2_ : 0x02EBDBC4
inflate       : 0x02EBDBC4

[Native Side (zlib)]
inflateInit2_ : 0x02EBCB74 
inflate       : 0x02BDB3E8
```

How can I fix this?

### Source Code

To reproduce this issue, clone this [repository](https://github.com/ied206/ZLibWrapper/tree/6ba68a38c7768ae3a6d86aebc411ec41d8836477) and run tests.

### Tested Envrionment

- zlibwapi.dll : zlib 1.2.11, compiled with VC2017
  (x86 : ReleaseWithoutAsm, x64 : Release)
- .Net Framework : 4.5, 4.5.2, 4.6.2, 4.7

EDIT: This issue does not happen when .Net Framework's `clrcompression.dll`, stripped version of zlib 1.2.3, is used instead of zlib 1.2.11.

Comment: Too much I can't see.  But the `ref` argument is very fishy, that suggests that ZStream is a struct.  You cannot pin a struct, the GCHandle.Alloc() call forces the struct to be boxed and you'll only pin the boxed copy.  If `_zstream` is a field of the class then you have to pin `this`.  Best thing to do is not having to pin at all by keeping it a local variable, store it back to the field afterwards.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, changing `ZStream` struct to class and removing `ref` fixed this issue! So the real reason was that GCHandle.Alloc cannot pin `ValueType`.

Comment: @HajinJang You might want to add that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Thanks to @HansPassant, I found out changing ZStream to class from struct fixed this issue. As a result, this ZLibWrapper package is working correctly. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Joveler.ZLibWrapper/